# how to open projects from developer.android.com?

Tags: android, eclipse

I downloaded the "LocationAware.zip" from http://developer.android.com/training/basics/location/geocoding.html. How to open this project in Eclipse now?

I would like to open it in Eclipse and then hit run to see how to run this app in the Emulator.

(new to Android - so sorry if the question is too basic)

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. Please note that developer questions are off topic on this site. I have flagged to question to be moved to the Stackoverflow website.

Answer (score 3):

To run the project you mentioned in Eclipse, hit 
- File->New->Project 
- Choose "Android Project From Existing Code" 
- Choose the root directory, hit finish.

Some extra steps you might need to take care after creating project (if there are errors)
1. Click Project->Clean (so that Resources "R" will be automatically generated)
2. If there are some XML errors, try to change Android Build Target (right click on project folder->Properties->Android)

Comment: Just for completeness, you might want step one to be "unzip the file you downloaded".